# Can I Integrate my desktop app with Django Authentication?

Tags: python, django, user-interface

I've been developing a graphical user interface with Python 2.7, wxPython, postgreSQL and SQLAlchemy. This gui is to see and extact data from sensors. I reached a point where a would like to have this softwate in multiple computer comunicating with a center database. To do this my GUI needs a authentication system, its been pretty hard for me to understand clearly how to make one from scratch.

Since my project at some point would like to have a website that have access to this database i began reseaching about django, and that it can use postgreSQL. Django has its own authentication library. I'm starting to set up the blog and all the authentication for the webpage in python 3.8.

my doubts are in if i can use this django authentication library and use it also to manage my desktop application since i want both of them o have access to the users and sensors data.

Comment: I don't see why not... you can use `urllib3` or `requests` libraries in your client application to contact the server, which should be sitting between the database and the clients that collect sensor data. You could create two `groups` of `users` one group for `humans` and the other group for `sensors-data-collectors` and use the `auth api` to `auth` and `POST` sensor data to the database.

Comment: @anu is good to see that I'm not that far from stablish. My aim is to deploy it in a Heroku server, set it up and try it. 

Another question. I add the data to the database via the pandas.to_sql(), this would change because of the method using now? or theres a way to use this in the 'POST' ?